# Trying to edit a form using django and python

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to edit the form via my edit button.

When i click update button in my form I'm getting the following error:

```
FieldError at /studentapp/editrow/72/
Cannot resolve keyword 'rowid' into field Choices are: address, course, id, name, pub_date, roll
```

My traceback shows the error originating in this line

```
item = get_object_or_404(Studentapp, rowid=id) this line.
```

My **models.py** looks like this:

```
class Studentapp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    roll = models.IntegerField()
    course = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.name, self.roll, self.course, self.address)

    def published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

**EDIT**

My view:

```
def editrow(request, id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Studentapp, id=id)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = EntryForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('studentapp:index'), id)
        else:
            form=EntryForm(instance=item)
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        form=EntryForm(instance=item)
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
```

My urls.py

```
url(r'^editrow/(?P<rowid>[0-9]+)/$', views.editrow, name='editrow'),
```

Form that i'm using to update the entry:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
  <form action="{% url 'studentapp:editrow' student_detail.id  %}" id="editform" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token%}

      <div class = "form-group">
    <label for = "your_name">
      Your name:
    </label>
    <input class = "form-control" id="new_name" type = "text" name="name" value="{{ student_detail.name }}" placeholder="Enter your name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for = "course_name">
      Course:
    </label>
    <input id="new_course" class = 'form-control' type = "text" name="course" value="{{ student_detail.course }}" placeholder="Enter your course">
  </div>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <label for = "rollno">
      Roll No.:
    </label>
    <input id="new_rollno" type = "text" class = 'form-control' name="roll" value="{{ student_detail.roll }}" placeholder="Enter your roll number">
  </div>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <label for ="addr">
      Address:
    </label>
    <input id="new_address" type = "text" name="address" class = 'form-control' value="{{ student_detail.address }}" placeholder="Enter your address"/>
  </div>
  <input type = "submit" value="Update" id="update" class = "btn btn-success" style="font-size:18px;" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire traceback

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'rowid' into field. Choices are: address, course, id, name, pub_date, roll

Comment: your model doesn't have this field `rowid=id`. you meant `id=id`

Comment: what should i do then?

Comment: remove `rowid`, and add `id`, because your model does not have this field

Comment: i'm new in django so i'm not able to understand what you're trying to say. can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is not right, your model does not have the field `rowid`

```
item = get_object_or_404(Studentapp, rowid=id) this line. # WRONG
item = get_object_or_404(Studentapp, id=id) this line. # OK
```

and your urls should be

```
url(r'^editrow/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.editrow, name='editrow'),

# url(r'^editrow/(?P<rowid>[0-9]+)/$', views.editrow, name='editrow'), # WRONG
```

Comment: i tried this method. i've removed rowid still it is showing "TypeError at /studentapp/editrow/72/
editrow() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rowid'" What to do now?

Comment: I've updated my question with my view. can you tell me the error?

Comment: your urls.py , please add everything that can be concerned. your urls pattern is important to detect what's worng

Comment: i've added my urls and form also

Comment: Check my answer, bugs were in your urls as well

Comment: I literally went through each and everything possible but i missed my urls. Thankyou so much for helping me out @Leymayzeur